# In kafka connect, what does a leader node usually do?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'd like to set a kafka-connect cluster in distributed mode.
Let me assume that there are 4 nodes here like this :

```
node1
node2
node3
node4
```

And I want to set the `node1` as `ADVERTISED_HOST` which is to set like a leader i guess. Also set the `node1`as `REST_HOST`, too.
So, when I run docker containers, I set environment variables to every node like below

```
    -e CONNECT_REST_HOST_NAME="node1" \
    -e CONNECT_REST_PORT="8083" \
    -e CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME="node1" \
    -e CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_PORT="8083" \
```

Then, I can see the phrase like `leaderUrl='http://node1:8083/'`from the log like this :

```
[2021-04-28 18:24:09,320] INFO Joined group and got assignment: Assignment{error=0, leader='connect-1-303380fb-90ff-4c00-a302-a57ee8b4a0e4', leaderUrl='http://node1:8083/', offset=93, connectorIds=[], taskIds=[test5-0, test5-2]} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder)
```

In this case, my point is,

- I read the docs that there is no leader in a kafka-connect cluster, but I think this `CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME` set a node as a leader;as you can see in the log. Am I wrong? If I misunderstood, what is the exact role of the `CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME` ?
- I thought that `CONNECT_REST_HOST_NAME` makes only one node get all the requests. But as I requested to node2 or node3 or node4, they WORKED WELL..! So I wonder what the exact role of this variable is.
- Finally, if there is the leader in the cluster, what does the leader node usually do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All nodes are equal, but they need a protocol to distribute tasks and report status to one another, or at least to the requesting client on the /status endpoint. Leadership is only temporary while task distribution occurs - you wouldn't want one server saying "work on tasks 1,2" while another says "2,3,4"

As a cluster, the nodes need to know how to refer to one another on the network, and this is what the advertised properties are for. The two other properties set the name in the logs/responses as well as the actual bound server port.

The advertised port is usually only different from the rest port when behind a proxy

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I got the concepts but still confused with the usage. Then, am I using those properties wrong? Do I have to set the advertised hostname as each own name, not the certain one for every node(like the way I do now)?

Comment: The advertised name should default to the OS hostname on its own. However, when this is in a container, it's some hexadecimal ID that you'd see in the first column of `docker ps`, and containers cannot communicate with each other on this name. If you use Docker Compose, the advertised name can be the service name, or you can explicitly start the container with its own hostname. In any other orchestrator, it largely depends on your network bridge, but advertising the physical host IP and forwarded connect server port will allow all inbound external traffic to resolve the cluster